# Using netty http server to transfer files

Tags: python, netty, python-requests

I am using netty to create an http server for some basic usage and file transfer. I used netty's [example](http://goo.gl/cEtwR3) for File server in order to learn how netty handles file transfers, and created a python client using requests module to transfer the file. The python code is:

```
r = requests.get("http://10.154.196.99:8000")
LOG.debug(r.headers)
LOG.debug(r.content)
with open('reports.csv', "wb") as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
```

r.content prints the contents of the file transfered correctly.But reports.csv is empty. Also when going to the address from my browser file gets downloaded normally, with contents. What do you think is the the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It worked but only I after I changed the code of while to this according to requests documentation for streaming files.

```
with open('reports.csv', "wb") as out_file:
    for chunk in r.iter_content():
        out_file.write(chunk)
```

Changing the file streamed by the server to a new one doesn't work. I can download the new file from web browser but not from requests and python.